# Does magento 2.4.4 works on php 7.4

Tags: php, magento, upgrade

I am planning to upgrade my magento version from 2.4.3 to 2.4.4

Will the new magento version 2.4.4 works well on php 7.4? Or it requires php 8 only

Answer (score 1):

Yes you need php8.1 for magento 2.4.4 and for more please follow below link.

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/system-requirements.html

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can read their announcement here were they respond to a question about php 7.4.

https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-DevBlog/Technical-platform-changes-to-expect-in-Adobe-Commerce-2-4-4/ba-p/485506

> In 2.4.4 we are adding full functional support for PHP 8.1 only. Merchant will be able to upgrade to 2.4.4 using PHP 7.4, however we do not test the full functional support of PHP 7.4 in 2.4.4

You could potentially do it but it's not supported and you will likely encounter many issues.

Answer (score 0):

Magento 2.4.4 installation itself require php 8.1 and once installed you can switch to  php 7.4.29 version

Answer (score 0):

You should use PHP 8.1 version.

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/system-requirements.html

Thanks,

Answer (score -1):

It's better to use 2.4.4 with PHP 7.4 for now

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31974296)